# Punishment for failing to impress the god of storytelling?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, curses

During the next session, my players will delve into an ancient temple of [Hlal, the Dragon God of Storytelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_deities#Hlal). There, they hope to find the ancient library of wondrous tales and hopefully the means of resurrecting their fallen comrade.

Of course, said Temple is (amongst various other perils) protected against people who try to get into the library by wards and riddles. One of the initial challenges for getting in will be a what is called "sacrificing of the soul", which in this case is more of a joke than a soul sacrificing.

The goal of that puzzle is to "gift" a story to a bookcase in order to advance. (There's a few requirements, such as it has to be a new story, the gifter must have written it, they can't keep a copy, and it has to be at least decent, since you're giving the story to a god)

Anyway; one of the possible outcomes is of course that they screw it up and either gift something terrible, don't figure out the requirements from the puzzle, or simple try to kick in the door.

If any of those things happen, I want the room to hit them with a fitting curse, but that's where I'm stuck. What kind of curse do you inflict upon people who fail to impress the (good natured) god of Storytelling?

Some of the things I'd like:

- It should be interesting (losing a level hurts, but it will quickly be forgotten)
- It should not be annoying (forced speaking in rhyme is fitting, but it also gets annoying real quick. They probably won't be able to cure it for a while)
- It should strike everyone somewhat fairly (losing points of Charisma might fit somewhat, but disproportianally hits the Bard)
- It doesn't *need* a mechanical part (roleplaying only also sounds great), but if it's mechanical it needs to work for a 4th level D&D 3.5e party.

Comment: this type of question really doesn't fit our format, you would probably be better off asking on a forum like enworld or in our chat than posting this as a site question.

Comment: Is there any way to salvage this question, or should I just abandon it? :)

Answer (score 1):

One idea depends on how robust your setting's history is and if your players are engaged with it.  Does it have famous legends that your players are familiar with?  Put the characters in an (illusionary/unreal) mini-quest where they are not themselves, rather are famous characters from the story.  The goal isn't to "win", but to replay the story, perhaps including a great sacrifice, etc.  This requires them to realize that they are in a story and identify which it is and how it should end.

Another concept could be to have the bards and storytellers who gain inspiration from Hlal to dream of the PCs and find their exploits and failures common knowledge when they return to civilization, starting with their fumble-handed approach to this.  It should inspire them to heroic ideals and ultimately give them the perk of wide fame, showing them the power of stories.  Which furthers the domain of a deity of stories.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have the God curse them to live a story worth telling him so whacky things always happen even when they try to go about things a smart and/or mundane way. Such a curse could force them to make will saves to not follow their compulsions.  It could also be as simple as they must solve their next problem without violence, but might bless them with a semi-permanent "freedom of movement" to do it.

Comment: Or go with making them talk in puns... ;-)

Comment: The only problem I can think of with speaking in puns/riddles/etc. is that the players themselves might forget or not be able to live up to the challenge although it might be a fun one in the right group.

Comment: Could have them draw literary cliches out of a hat and that's what they have to act like until some goal is met or greater restoration or something is cast.